# How to dynamic change <INPUT Value="...> in a web page on a client

Tags: configuration, webserver, esp8266

I work on a web based configuration interface between a ESP8266 based sever and a client (firefox). The page is based on a  encapsulated table with  tags. An  has an attribute value="  " which allows to give the name="  " attribute a predefined value. This value is displayed in a page and can be changed by the uses and send back to the server as config data upon a Summit.
The page is stored in PROGMEM and I can not access the value="  " attributes in order to update them in case the new entered config data changes them.

== My question is: Is there and if so what is the method to GET this fixed in PROGMEM stored page to the client with updated config data.

== If there is no method to do this what is the best way to display an PROGMEM based web page with dynamic config data.

[Config page with some predefined values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJqqO.png)

```html
<FORM action="/" method="post" id="userform">
<table Class="TR1">   
<Caption Class="CAP">   Product characteristics </Caption>
<thead class="TR1">   
<tr>   
 <Th class="TH1"> Group </Th>
 <Th class="TH2"> Parameter </Th>
 <Th class="TH3"> Value </Th>
 <Th class="TH4"> Type </Th>
 <Th class="TH5"> Subval </Th>
 <Th class="TH5">  </Th>
 <Th class="TH5">  </Th>
</TR>      
</Thead>   
<tbody class="TR1">   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1"> Network </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> SSID </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="ssid" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Password </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="password"  name="password" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Encryption </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input list="encrypcion"  name="encrypcion" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Key nr </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="number" name="keynr" min="1" max="4" value="1" step="1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> IPaddess </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="IPaddess" value="192.168.1.xxx" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> DHCP </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> Yes: <INPUT type="radio" name="DHCP" value="1"> &nbsp &nbsp No: <INPUT type="radio" name="DHCP" value="0">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>      
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1"> Serial </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Port nr </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="number" name="sprt" min="1" max="4" value="1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Baud rate </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input list="baudrate" name="baudrate"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Serial frame </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input list="sframe" name="sframe"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>      
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1"> Calendar </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Time </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="time" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Date </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="date" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Alarm 1 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="alarm1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Alarm 2 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="alarm2" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1"> MQTT </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> User </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="user" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Pasword </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="password"  name="password" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Server </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="server" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Port </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="number" name="mqttprt" min="1880" value="1883" step="1" placeholder=1883 onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Topic 1 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="topic1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4"> Type </TD>
 <Td class="TD5"> <input list="ttype" name="ttype"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Topic 2 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="topic2" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4"> Type </TD>
 <Td class="TD5"> <input list="ttype" name="ttype"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Topic 3 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="topic3" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4"> Type </TD>
 <Td class="TD5"> <input list="ttype" name="ttype"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
<tr class="TR1">   
 <Td class="TD1">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD2"> Topic 4 </TD>
 <Td class="TD3"> <input type="text"  name="topic4" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD4"> Type </TD>
 <Td class="TD5"> <input list="ttype" name="ttype"> </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
 <Td class="TD5">  </TD>
</TR>   
   
</tbody>   
<tfoot>   
<tr class="FT1">   
 <td colspan="7"> EOT </td>
</tr>   
</tfoot>   
</TABLE>   
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your ESP8266 serve up an additional JavaScript file which simply set some global variables. This file would be re-created from the config values by the ESP8266 each time it is requested.

So when the browser makes a request: `GET /config.js HTTP/1.1`

The server responds with:

```
window.config = {
  ssid: "my network ssid",
  password: "my network password",
  //... continue with other config values
};
```

Make sure you include a script tag in your html to make the browser fetch the JS file. In order to set the initial `value` of the `<input>` tags, you might use a bit more JS:

```
<body>
  ...
  <!-- put this at the end of your HTML <body> -->
  <script src="/config.js"></script>
  <!-- now you can access your `window.config` in javascript -->

  <script>
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    // make sure names used in config.js match an input's `name` attribute
    input.value = window.config[input.name]; 
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

In summary, you serve a static (never changing) HTML document that is stored in PROGMEM.

1. When the browser loads the page, and the `<table>` is rendered, but all the `<input>` elements initially have blank values.
2. The browser sees `<script src="/config.js">` and goes back to the server to get `config.js`.
3. The ESP8266 constructs `config.js` and sends it to the browser.
4. The browser runs `config.js`, which stores some values in `window.config`.
5. The final  runs and sets the values of the `<input>` elements.

Feel free to comment if you get stuck. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help I found a method at W3C dealing with ID. This works for me.

Comment: Always glad for good news! If I may ask, what method did you use?

Comment: I added "ID" to the tags and used  document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "test to display" to the java script. that worked nice for me. I'm working on a home automation system and need a "simple" web page to manage the appliances and different configuration settings for the system based on a ESP8266. I'm planning to step over to a esp32. I'm not a supper programmer but neither a starter. Sometimes I need need some help and I appreciate it that you took the  time to do so.

Comment: I did press some up down button at the top. One I discoverer was if the answer was useful. and the other not use full. I did want to say that the answer was useful to me.